# lync 2010 + exchange 2010 on same server

Tags: exchange, lync

I'm attempting to build a test infrastructure Active Directory + Lync + Exchange. After installing Lync on my Exchange Server, I was unable to connect to Exchange. I don't know for sure that I was able to connect to Exchange before I installed Lync though. Rather than go through the installation process again, I'm hoping if someone can tell me for sure if Lync 2010 and Exchange 2010 can exist on the same server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's supposedly not support by Microsoft.  The biggest things you'll run into deal with the fact that both Exchange and Lync use IIS and listen on the default ports of 80 and 443.

You are better off having Lync on it's own server...just use a VM.

Comment: Could you not bind each one to a different IP address? Only asking as I'm looking to do the same thing for a small office where an additional server feels like overkill!

Comment: Chris, in theory you can probably do that, but see here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvarro/archive/2012/04/15/lync-server-2010-and-sharepoint-on-the-same-server-gt-not-supported.aspx if you plan on using UM as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're installing them in seperate VMs, you'll need a reverse proxy or ISA server or Threat Management Gateway or a good wired-router to figure out what the originator is requesting.

For example, Lync traffic, to Lync VM. 
Exchange traffic, to exchange VM.